# "Missing a required architecture" while doing the final run with CodeSign

Tags: xcode, xcode4, code-signing, app-store-connect

An alert comes with the message that the app couldn't run because the file is missing and then this is the warning:

```
warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.    At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 (-19033)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

What am I missing here?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this settings:

```
Project -> Build Settings -> Valid Architectures == armv6 armv7
                          -> Build Active Architecture Only == NO
```

Comment: Yes, it does look exactly like this :/

Comment: It is set to "no" for both release and debug under Build Archive Architecture only if that is what You mean

Comment: Yes, i mean that. What about valid architectures?

Comment: there, it says armv6 armv7
:((

Comment: It is the latest beta, I wanted to verify the app works totally with iOS 5.0
Will I need to download 4.1?
If yes, do I just open the whole project in it or?
Thank You for Your help!

Comment: I think it is not possible now to upload binary to app store via beta releases of Xcode. If I help you don't forget to accept my answer and up vote =)

Comment: don't worry! :)
just one last question then,
when I download the Xcode 4.1, can I just open the .xcodeproj with it or something more complicated?

Comment: I hope, that you can open project in Xcode 4.1 and try to build without any changes.